# How to prevent Android library from causing proguard collision errors?

Tags: gradle, proguard, android-library

I produce an Android library that has a transitive dependency on OkHttp. I've received reports that when my users include my library, they see the following error:

`More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/proguard/okhttp3.pro'`

I know that I can recommend that they exclude the file in their `build.gradle`, like this:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/proguard/okhttp3.pro'
}
```

However, I'd really prefer to fix the issue on my side if possible, but I don't entirely understand what's causing the problem. As far as I can tell, my library (as an AAR) doesn't have any META-INF directory. What is causing this error, and how can I fix it?